# Separate CPU and IO time

Tags: c, linux, io, profiling

I have an application with a lot of IO. This application is multithreaded and has a single thread dedicate to IO requests and hence some of the time, IO and CPU is overlapped.

It is written in C for Linux.

I would like to know how much useful work the CPU is doing. For instance, if we made a perfect RAID system we may be able to reduce significantly (if not eliminate) the IO factor. Afterwards, we are limited by the main memory and CPU throughput. How can I know this? How can I measure this?

Thanks
Bob

Answer (score 3):

The [`time(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) utility or the [`getrusage(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage) system call can give you some timing information.  Any time your process doesn't spend executing code is time it spends blocked on I/O.

Comment: Well, almost all the time, but on an otherwise unused machine, wall clock time - CPU time is a good indication. +1.

Comment: I looked at the man page of time and getrusage. The time command has a subsection called IO, but (ironically) they have nothing to do with timing really. The getrusage can separate based on user and kernel time, but kernel time doesn't necessarily translate to IO time. I know how to get the wall time, but how do I measure the "CPU time" as larsmans suggests. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Bob Dole, the CPU time is the user time plus the kernel time reported by `time`.  The real time is wall clock time.  The `time` utility doesn't measure I/O time.. as @larsmans mentioned it just measures the amount of useful execution your program has done.  Any discrepancy between wall clock time and execution time is time your process spent blocked - most often for I/O, assuming your machine isn't loaded down doing a bunch of other things.

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you so much, Carl. Out of curiosity, do you know what happens for multithreaded applications? For example, if the process runs for 10 seconds and there are two threads that are 100% utilised running. Does that mean the real time is 20 seconds or still 10? Thank you again.

Comment: @Bob Dole, most of the time real time is literally real time.  The system and user times are CPU time, so they might go as high as real time times the number of processors you have.